# Is there a "de facto" standard link to give to users to show them how to enable JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

This is an often used HTML piece on websites.

```
<noscript>
Please enable JavaScript or use a JavaScript capable device to get the maximum benefit of this site.
</noscript>
```

I want to link it to some directions or similar to enable JavaScript. I don't want to make my own list, as it would require *me* to update it.

I have found the [Google link](https://www.google.com/support/adsense/bin/answer.py?answer=12654) before, which was pretty good, but I was wondering if there is any *de facto* link that developers link to give users step by step instructions on how to enable JavaScript.

I realise that most people with it off probably *do* know how to re-enable it, I just thought for completeness a link couldn't hurt (maybe their more web savvy brother disabled it on a shared computer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looked up a bit and found http://www.enable-javascript.com/.

Seems to be a bit more updated i.e includes chrome etc and has screen images as well for those who prefer the visual route.

Also, doesn't seem to have a lot of pesky ads etc. Hope it helps!

Caveat: Must add that I have never used this before and am not sure of how frequently it will be updated but it looks promising!

Comment: Very nice site. Has potential to become a defacto standard. It's as well funny to see how many steps it require to accomplish the task in various browsers :)

Answer (score 1):

Is this still a major concern in 2010? In my experience, people who see the `<noscript>` content have either:

- disabled JS themselves, and therefore would know how to enable it (e.g. NoScript users)
- or don't have JS capabilities (e.g. text-only or low-end mobile browsers)

Above that, browser landscape is varied enough that it's rather hard to keep up with various browser versions and their JS settings.

I'd say "just display 'this works better with JS' and degrade gracefully".

Answer (score 0):

I have found [activatejavascript.org](http://www.activatejavascript.org/). It is a little outdated, e.g. not providing instructions for Google Chrome.

I am also weary of sites that look like just a quick + dirty platform for advertisements (I got that impression).

There is probably something better.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do it yourself?

It only takes a little browser sniffing and browser screenshots.

Comment: Because I don't want to have to maintain it.